# How can a service tell if the controller that injected it is destroyed?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm having a service that polls the server and caches the results and I want it to stop doing that and clear it's cache once it is no longer needed. Here is what I've tried:

```
angular.module('app', []).
service('MyService', function(){
    var cache = [];
    var ctrls = 0;

    return {
         init: function(scope){
            // Keep track of how many controllers have injected this service
            ctrls++;
            // Also keep track of how many of those controllers get destroyed
            scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
                ctrls--;
                // Clear the cache once it's not needed!
                if(ctrls === 0){cache.length = 0;}
            });
         }
    }
}).
controller('MyController', function($scope, MyService){
    MyService.init($scope);
});
```

While this works, it is error prone, and relies on code on the controller in order to work properly

Is there a standard, angulary, way of knowing when "whatever injected this thing, no longer exists" inside the service itself, **without** relying on code outside of the service itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do that is to decorate the $injector, but it's not possible.
BUT, you can "override" the $injector's get function, and then call the original get, like this:

```
angular.module('yourApp').config(['$injector', function ($injector) {
    // The function we'll be called after the original get
    counterFunc = function () {
        // do your counting here
        console.log("injector called ", arguments[0]);
    };

    // Get a copy of the injector's get function
    var origGetFunc = $injector.get;

    //Override injector's get with our own
    $injector.get = function() {

        // Call the original get function
        var returnValue = origGetFunc.apply(this, arguments);

        // Call our function
        counterFunc.apply(this,arguments);

        return returnValue;
    }
}]);
```